# Windows 8 input[type="range"] styling

Tags: html, css, windows-8

I'm trying to style my sliders on Windows 8 (IE 10) they have some standard styling and I can't find their styling within the documentation, anyone else who have had to style the slider (I just want to change the color)

See picture below to see Windows 8 standard styling (IE 10):

[image: Slider image win8 design]

I want to change the purple element of the slider to, for instance, red.
I'm not posting code because I can't find out where to look for it, not even in the inspect mode in my Visual Studio debug screen.

---

In addition to this question i wanna ask if you know how to style the select controls i can manage all the other but the blue one on the picture below

[image: select & options]

Comment: I think you cant change the style for the native controls

Comment: It must be given some place, iv'd read page up and down, trough guidelines for this and still no real answer, the guidelines tell you to use which direction and which label and such stuff, nothing about styling the slider

Comment: can you share your sources or guidelines on which you are working

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465473.aspx follow the link above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution have been found!
The fill in the controler is set by this new -ms- (IE) property

FX this would make it black

```
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower{background-color:#000;}
```

EDIT*(

```
input[type="range"]:hover::-ms-fill-lower{background-color:#fff;}
```

)

More controls are found by building [THIS](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Common-HTML-controls-and-09a72a24/sourcecode?fileId=50872&pathId=1927408783) following links content on a windows 8 and visual studio 2012 edition.

Comment: kinda hard cause its only working in win8, its a metro app
but i can post my code ??

Answer (score 0):

Simon's answer doesn't work unless you put a selector in front of it:

```
#sliderId::-ms-fill-lower { background-color: #ff0000; }
#sliderId::-ms-fill-upper { background-color: #0000ff; }
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465745.aspx)

Comment: i thought that would be obvious to anybody?? no pseudo class works without a selector infront

Comment: `::selection` does ... at least it does in my win8 app